# How can I deny users to add/modify/remove printers to cups?

Tags: macos, authorization, cups

I am using Mac OS X 10.6.  I wrote a program which will add and remove printers to a CUPS server using libcups.  It works, but now I am considering the security aspects.  This program takes a user name and password to authenticate on the CUPS server.  Whatever user name and password I use, it works as long as it is valid on the system.  How do I restrict access to only a specific user ?

Regards
Alan

Answer (score 0):

Check for membership in a particular group.  That would be the standard unix way to do it, anyway.  Let the system's authentication framework figure out who's a member of a group (could be /etc/group, could be LDAP or Active Directory, doesn't matter).

Comment: you mean something like adding *Require user @GROUP* to the cupsd.conf ? That is not doing the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Start Safari on your Mac and point it to http://localhost:631/help/ref-cupsd-conf.html

Look up the sections about authorization and *Policy*, *Location*, *Limit*, *IPP OPerations* and the like.

Basically, you can set up very fine-grained "Policies", defined in cupsd.conf, which regulate access and denial to any IPP operation on a CUPS server.

A detailed example is to be found on `http://localhost:631/help/policies.html` .